# Autodesk Forge - downloaded item has a different name

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I'm using the `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName` endpoint to download an item (a Revit model) from BIM 360. Using [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/) documentation. The file gets downloaded fine and the contents are correct however, after downloading, the file name is the GUID of the file (4aac519c-ab91-42a5-85c5-f023c82d4736.rvt) , not the 'displayName' of the file (my file.rvt) . I'm getting the file name like so:

```
var headervalue = resp.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Content-Disposition")?.Value;
string contentDispositionString = Convert.ToString(headervalue);
ContentDisposition contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(contentDispositionString);
fileName = contentDisposition.FileName;
```

I've used the same method on another project and it's working fine. The content and the file name of the file both are correct. However somehow the endpoint is behaving differently on this project.

Any pointers what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is mentioned somewhere in the documentation but I don't think you should rely on the `Content-Disposition` of the response headers for this. If you want to get a filename for whichever object you're downloading, you should always get it from the actual item record (obtained in the 3rd step of the tutorial you linked to).

Comment: I did that first. But it's not going to work when the rvt file has rvt links in it that are also on BIM 360 docs. In this case the file you download will be a zip file that contains the main item you requested and its rvt links. I can't tell if the file is going to be rvt or zip so I'm getting the actual file name from `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: I see. I still believe you should be able to find out from the the JSON API responses whether the file you want to download has some other designs linked to it or not. Try exploring the response from the https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/ endpoint, and see if it provides additional indices on whether the Revit file has other files linked to it.